# ggplot with "Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x, y, colour " error

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I have a for loop to create a series of graphs, but keep getting the error noted above ("Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x, y, colour"). When I run the code without the loop, it runs properly.

```
tmp.df <- melt(data, 
               id.vars = c("Period", "source", "Bsl_Cat", "scenario"), 
               measure.vars = c("tot.loss", "freq"), 
               na.rm = TRUE)

for(i in seq_along(UoM)) {   
  ggplot() +    
    geom_line(data = subset(tmp.df, 
                            source == source1 & 
                              scenario == scenario & 
                              tmp.df$Bsl_Cat == "CPBP" & 
                              variable == "freq"),
              aes(y = value, x = Period, color = source1)) + 
    geom_line(data = subset(tmp.df, 
                            source == source2 & 
                              scenario == scenario & 
                              tmp.df$Bsl_Cat ==  "CPBP" & 
                              variable == "freq"),
              aes(y = value, x = Period, color = source2)) +   
    labs(x="Date", y = "Frequency per Quarter") + 
    scale_color_manual(labels = c("USAA", "ABA"), values = mycolors2) +
    ggtitle(paste(UoM[i])) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "plain")) +
    theme(legend.direction = "horizontal", 
          legend.position = "bottom", 
          legend.title = element_blank()) 
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you give an example of the data? There's a `dput`function you could use.

Comment: Does show.legend=FALSE make the error go away? That might help us guide you a bit more into it.